# Set SSL using existing Certificate in Jetty Embedded

Tags: java, ssl, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am working on a web application writen in Java using Jetty Embedded. And My manager wants me to configure SSL. He gave me two files: 'server.key' and 'server.crt'.

the 'server.key' looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[Base64]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

the 'server.crt'

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Base64]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried to look for tutorials online but I just can not get it to work...

I converted the crt file to a jks file using the command:

```
keytool -keystore server.jks -import -alias <alias> -file server.crt -trustcacerts
```

But when I start the server everything loads fine and it says it started the server with 'SSL--HTTP/1.1' on addess 0.0.0.0:443.
But whenever i try to connect to it from chrome it tries to establish secure connection and than just say "This site can’t be reached".

This is my main server code:

```
JSONObject config = new JSONObject(FileUtils.read("data/config.json"));
String sslKeystore = config.getString("keystore_file");
String sslPassword = config.getString("keystore_password");

QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
threadPool.setMaxThreads(500);

Server server = new Server(threadPool);
server.addBean(new ScheduledExecutorScheduler());

ServletContextHandler app = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
app.setContextPath("/");


app.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultHandler()), "/*");


HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();

handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { app, requestLogHandler});

server.setHandler(handlers);

NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog("data/logs/requests/TicketTracker-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log");
requestLog.setRetainDays(90);
requestLog.setAppend(true);
requestLog.setExtended(false);
requestLog.setLogServer(true);
requestLog.setLogLatency(true);
requestLog.setLogCookies(true);
requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT");
requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
requestLogHandler.setServer(server);

HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(sslKeystore);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(sslPassword);
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(sslPassword);

ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                                    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
                                    new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
sslConnector.setPort(443);

server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { sslConnector });

server.start();
server.join();
```

the passwords are the same as the alias.

The main problem I don't know where to look... Because it doesn't crashes, It doesn't give me an error, It just doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have PEM encoded certificates with you ? I mean it contains a root file , intermediate file , and main ssl certificate file . If it is there i can help. Or paste the name of files you have in your certificate folder.

Comment: @codechat , the only two files i have are the server.crt and the server.key (there is also the generated server.jks), We usually use these with apache.